# How do I delete one attribute in LDAP with LDIF?

Tags: ldap, ldif

How do I delete one attribute in LDAP with LDIF? I an trying to delete `uniqueMember: cn=jsmith,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com` can someone please show me the LDIF to do it?

```
dn: cn=USER,ou=groups,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: USER
uniqueMember: cn=jsmith,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
uniqueMember: cn=guest,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
uniqueMember: cn=admin,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
uniqueMember: cn=ford,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
dn: cn=USER,ou=groups,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: uniqueMember
uniqueMember: cn=jsmith,ou=users,dc=s2rsolutions,dc=com
```